# IBM Websphere startServer.bat and adding projects

Tags: java, websphere, application-server, ibm-rad

I am trying to start the websphere server outside of eclipse/rad.

From: 
SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin

I runt the startServer.bat server1

It starts correctly. Now I am wondering how I can "Add/remove projects" to have the same effect as when doing it from inside RAD.

Possible?

Comment: You won't be able to add projects using startServer.bat. This question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926981/deploy-ear-file-to-was-7-from-command-line

Comment: No, its not. That one is trying to install it on an another server. I am just trying to install it locally. Is it: $AdminApp install /path/to/localfile.war {-contextroot whatever ...more options...} 

what is $AdminApp ? Is it possible with an unpacked ear ?

Comment: $AdminApp is a Jacl variable that resolves to a builtin command that provides an interactive/simplified interface to com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagement.

Answer (score 1):

You got to write scripts to do that. Jacl/Jython scripts are available to perform this activity.

Refer to these samples to start with:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html

AdminApp is the one that you would use to administrate the application related components. This is one the 4 key control objects available in Jacl/Jython in the WebSphere environment.

HTH
Manglu